# Use a Launch Screen and Launch Image in Asset Catalog

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, launch-screen

My app supports iOS7 and iOS8. I want to use the new Launch Screen xibs for iOS8, but since I'm targetting iOS7, I get this warning:

> Applications using Launch Screen Files and targetting iOS 7.1 and
>   earlier need to also include a Launch Image in an Asset Catalog.

I had removed my Launch Screen Images from the Asset Catalog, so I put them back to make the warning go away. However, when I do that, then my app always shows the Launch Image instead of the new Launch xib, even if I'm using iOS 8.

How can I have a hybrid set up that chooses the Launch Screen File for iOS8 and falls back to the Launch Screen Image Assets for iOS 7?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I gave up on using Launch Screen Xib for iOS 8 and used the launch screen images instead. If you really want to use a Xib then create a view controller in storyboard, add all your images, uilabel etc in it and then automatically redirect that view controller to move on to next view controller.